# passing variable to another function in PHP

Tags: php

In following function:

```
function dateSelect($monthname,$dayname,$yearname) {
   echo "rs: " . $monthname;    
  dropdownDateSelect($monthName, $dayName, $yearName);    
}
```

`$monthname` gets echoed out correctly. However, it is empty inside function `dropdownDateSelect`. I am not sure why. I am getting "Variable `$monthName` seems to be uninitialized" error message in `Netbeans IDE`.

```
function dropdownDateSelect($monthName, $dayName, $yearName){
  echo "rss: " . $monthName;
}
```

Now in`"rss: $monthName"`, `$monthName` is empty.

Could you elaborate why this is happening and how I can pass `$monthName` to `dropdownDateSelect` function?

Thank you.

Comment: monthName  != monthname

Comment: `$monthname` != `$monthName`

Comment: @Fred-ii- 1 second fast..

Comment: @SubinThomas my copy failed lol darn FF

Comment: however for some reason, I'm not convinced about that ^

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Why don't you put it in an answer then?

Comment: @Fred-ii- : Still 2 up votes for this question..!!!????

Comment: @Jan because I have a sneaking suspicion that that's not the problem. My *"Spidey sense"* is tingling for some reason.

Comment: @SubinThomas crazy huh? lol

Comment: I honestly don't know what you're trying to do here. You have a function inside a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be aware of upper- and lowercase as they are not the same in PHP (see also the comments above). So this is how your function will work (with `$monthName`):

```
function dateSelect($monthName, $dayName, $yearName) {
    echo "rs: " . $monthName;    
    dropdownDateSelect($monthName, $dayName, $yearName);    
}
```

Comment: if that's what it is, great. We'll wait for what the OP has to say ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- [Take this](http://www.comicvine.com/forums/spider-man-167/how-do-you-beat-the-spider-sense-23767/)! I may quote: "When deprived of his spider-sense, Spider-Man becomes vulnerable to surveillance and attack and traveling by web-line requires most of his concentration."

Comment: @Jan Thank you so much. I am so silly and you caught it so quick.

Comment: No worries. Indeed, Subin Thomas and Fred were battling each other in the first place...